# section id not being recognised within jquery scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parallax scrolling website which works via section ID's. I have animations on each of the sections but only want them to activate when the section is in the viewport. I currently have the following, which doesn't seem to be working. I'm fairly new to jquery/javascript so any help would be appreciated!

```
function paintLine(){
  $('#3-Backup-3').lazylinepainter({
    "svgData": svgData,
    'ease': 'easeInOutQuad',
    'strokeCap': 'square'
  }).lazylinepainter('paint'); 
}

var element_position = $('#backup-section-3').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = element_position;


    if(_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
        paintLine();
    }
});

 <!-- Backup 3 -->    
              <div data-anchor="backup-section-3" class="section backup-section-3">
                <div class="float-left">
                  <div id="backup-nav">
                    <p onclick="openSideNavGreen()" class="nav-section-title">Backup</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p class="backup-text-title">Methods</p>
                    <p class="backup-text">No surprises here then: tape as a primary backup method remains at an all-time low of 3%. This is the first year it hasn’t fallen – possibly indicative of how stubborn some legacy systems (often populated with static compliance data) can be. I wouldn’t be surprised to see similar figures next year.<br><br>We did see a drop in the prevalence of combined disk/tape solutions, with a new option, External Hard Drive/USB, seeming the preferred choice instead.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right"> 
                <div id="3-Backup-3"></div> 
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#backup-section-3').offset().top;` refers to an element with an **ID** of `backup-section-3` which you don't seem to have in your HTML markup. Try giving the element that you're referring to an ID of `backup-section-3` and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: data-anchor="backup-section-3" is the section ID, the nav bar currently runs using these ID's so I know that they already work

Comment: Your navigation bar is using jquery to access these elements, or is it using hrefs with #? An anchor `#` is much different than a `#` in JQuery. If you need to see this visually, please see: https://jsfiddle.net/o5n2fgrt/ Notice how the `data-anchor` div remains empty.

Comment: I'm using hrefs with #

Comment: @JessCauchi As I thought. Again, `#` in JQuery is looking for an **ID**, not a `data-anchor`. Your element needs `id="backup-section-3"`. If you do a `console.log(element_position);` in your `scroll` function, it will return undefined because you are looking for the Y-Position of an element that does not exist.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/o5n2fgrt/1/

Comment: Just change `<div data-anchor="backup-section-3" class="section backup-section-3">` to `<div id="backup-section-3" data-anchor="backup-section-3" class="section backup-section-3">`

Comment: I tried adding an id to the div and it doesn't work. When I run other jquery code using the data anchor it does work though

Comment: @JessCauchi Can you go into your console (F12) with that page open and let me know if it returns any errors?

Comment: It doesn't return any errors, which is the strange thing

Answer (score 0):

id needs the start with alpha character. put any alpha char in front of the 3 in your javascript and html and it will work.